# spring boot import another spring boot project as dependency using component scan

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have `common` and `product-service`. `common` has `@RestControllerAdvice RestExceptionHandler`. When I add `common` to pom.xml of `product-service` RestExceptionHandler is not working.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.gucardev</groupId>
      <artifactId>common</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

If I add only "common" to product-service using `@ComponentScan({"com.gucardev.common"})` now ExceptionHandler works but product-service endpoints are not found. However if I add itself and common like:

`@ComponentScan({"com.gucardev.productservice", "com.gucardev.common"})`

now it works.

Why should I add itself of package to `@ComponentScan` in `product-service`?

for more info about my `common` package build config:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            </exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>repackage</id>
            <configuration>
              <classifier>exec</classifier>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```